# rails http get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest

I am trying to connect with an external API (via get request). I use Net Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(link)). Suppose that link is the link I want to get request from.
The problem is that when I run this request does not do what it has to do ( authenticate a user, based on some passwords and tokens); but if I use manually this link ( via browser) it works. Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance.

P.S. I am completely new to Rails

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of resources on what you are trying to accomplish.  What you are doing, is using "Ruby", not rails, to send a request to an external provider using the HTTP GET method.

If I may make a suggestion - which will accomplish that task -

[Net::HTTP.get_response(url, path_to_svc)](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response)

Your code would look like -

```
json = Net::HTTP.get_response("apps.db.ripe.net", "/whois/lookup/ripe/inetnum/127.0.0.1.json").body
puts json
```

this was tested, and works.

Comment: First of all thank you a lot. here is my(your) code to see what exactly I mean.
'json = Net::HTTP.get_response("google.com", "/ssoAPI?blah/blah").body' this one does not do the action I want
but if use  the link on my browser google.com/ssoAPI?blah/blah does the action I want. Bare in mind that I do not want to receive something just to log in to another platform. The google link I am using is just for an example.